# Получение значения переменной класса переданного по ссылке

Tags: c#

В `Recipients`  есть метод, который вызван из `SENDER` и обращается к переменной класса `SENDER` таким образом: `mainSender.SENDER.pathToSpace`. Но я получаю сообщение, что ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр класса. Подскажите, как сделать правильно?

**MAIN**

```
private void mainSender_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      settings = new settings();
      log = new log(this);
      mysql = new mysql(this);

      Senders = new Senders(this);
      Recipients = new Recipients(this);
      SENDER = new sender(this);

}
```

**Recipients**

```
internal Recipients(mainServer mainServerIn)
{

    mainServer = mainServerIn;
}

internal List<string> getFromWindows()
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    result = Directory.GetDirectories(mainSender.SENDER.pathToSpace + @"\").Select(directoryInfo => new DirectoryInfo(directoryInfo).Name).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

**SENDER**

```
internal sender(mainSender mainSenderIn)
{

     mainSender = mainSenderIn;

     pathToSpace = mainSender.settings.senderPathToSpace;

     syncWindowsMysqlRicipients();
  
  }

internal void syncWindowsMysqlRicipients()
{
     List<string> listFromWindows = mainSender.Recipients.getFromWindows();
}
```

В методе **syncWindowsMysqlRicipients()** я получаю ошибку

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: @igor Я вызываю метод Recipients из класса SENDER, которому для выполнения нужно значение из класса SENDER.. Main класс служит проводником, т к содержит ссылки на все классы... Но я получаю ошибку, т к передал ссылку main (this) класса, когда класс SENDER не был ещё инициализирован..

Comment: @igor возможно, мне необходимо обновить каким-то образом ссылку, потому что нужная мне переменная инициализируется в конструкторе SENDER..

Comment: Зачем этот рассказ? Покажите код.

Comment: @igor пожалуйста

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/26077/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите

```
syncWindowsMysqlRicipients();
```

из конструктора `sender`.

В этом методе происходит обращение к `mainSender.SENDER` до того, как левой части в

```
SENDER = new sender(this);
```

присваивается значение.

Comment: эта строчка в другом этого класса методе... это я для краткости

Comment: у меня в конструкторе вызывается этот метод..

Comment: @EHQ Я ничего не понял. Кто "он"? В каком методе?

Comment: я обновил код..

Comment: Если я убираю этот метод из конструктора SENDER и вызываю из main - это работает) можете объяснить?

Comment: буду знать, спасибо

Comment: здравствуйте, а с Вами можно как-то связаться?

Comment: @EHQ Можно, и Вы только что это сделали :).

Comment: просто у меня другой вопрос.. ) мне нужно реализовать кое-что.. и возможно, Вы могли бы подсказать мне, как это сделать лучше и проще...